# Flutter transfer-add-copy collection to subcollection

Tags: flutter, firebase, algorithm

First of all thanks for everything already now. Solutions of the problems are so important for me, you can contact with me from ayberkguns@gmail.com or Ayberk#0342 from discord. I can give WhatsApp as well If you want to help me.

Hi, I am new of flutter. I create a project about smartboard books. Users can login with email and password. They can register with email, password and fullname. Then they can preview and purchase the all books. I listed the books with these codes. Finally when I add to book information for example book image url, book name, book price, book buttons etc. into the firebase, the program is adding the book into the list automatically. I added the preview webview and stripe but I need help about 3 subject.

- Firstly users when purchase the book with stripe, if stripe callback is true (By the way I couldn't see how can I set true or false) which book the user bought should be transfer from these collection to users subcollection. I mean for example into my firebase I have almost 120-130 different books into 5 different collections. In this case, it should be if the customer buy the X book into highschool, the book collection should be transfer to current user's subcollection. So the user can see the bought books everytime he/she login. And at the same time I can list current user's  boutght book into Mybooks page automatically like the other pages. When system is creating user, the system is not creating ''Mybooks'' subcollection at the same time not yet. I should create that too.
- Secondly this problem probably have a easy solution but I couldn't saw. If the user already have the book, when click to purchase button the program should message 'You have already this book!'.
- And the last one, I have already searchbar into 5 different pages. But the searchbar looking into firestore book collection. I need to searcbar for Mybookspage as well. But the searchbar should look at the current user's bought book data.

Also I put my stripe code as well. I tried it with test mode and test cards. Error or Success are working good. Should I set another something and how can I set the mode from test mode to real mode?

This is my highschool books page.

```
class HighschoolPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HighschoolPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HighschoolPage> createState() => _HighschoolPageState();
}

class _HighschoolPageState extends State<HighschoolPage> {

  String bookNameText = '';
  Map<String, dynamic>? paymentIntent;












  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFF1f1545),
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("High School Books"),
          elevation: 0.0,
          leading: DrawerWidget(),
        ),

        body: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 16, right: 16, left: 16, top: 16),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              TextField(
                onChanged: (val){
                  setState(() {
                    bookNameText = val;
                  });
                },
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontFamily: 'Montserrat', fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  filled: true,
                  fillColor: Colors.white,
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                    borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                  ),
                  hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                  hintText: "Search for the books",
                  prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
                  prefixIconColor: Colors.black,
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 20.0,),
              StreamBuilder<List<HighschoolBooksModel>>(
                  stream: FirestoreHelper_Highschool.read(),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
                    }
                    if (snapshot.hasError) {
                      return Center(child: Text("Some Error Occured",style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                        fontSize: 20,
                      ),),);
                    }
                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      final userData = snapshot.data;
                      return Expanded(
                        child: FutureBuilder(
                            builder: (context,snapshot) {
                              return userData!.length == 0 ? Center(
                                child: Text(
                                  "Not result found",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                    fontSize: 20,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              )
                                  : ListView.builder(
                                  itemCount: userData.length,
                                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                    final singleUser = userData[index];
                                    if(singleUser.bookname!.toString().toLowerCase().contains(bookNameText.toLowerCase()) || singleUser.booklevel!.toString().toLowerCase().contains(bookNameText.toLowerCase())) {
                                      return ListTile(
                                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                        title: Text(
                                          '${singleUser.bookname!}\n''${singleUser.booklevel!}',
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              color: Colors.white,
                                              fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
                                        ),
                                        subtitle: Row(
                                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                          children: [
                                            if(singleUser.status == 0)...[
                                              text_button_getinfo(context, index),
                                            ] else
                                              ...[
                                                text_button_preview(context, index),
                                                text_button_purchase(context, index),
                                              ]
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                        trailing: Text(
                                          '${singleUser.pricesembol!}',
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                            fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                                            fontSize: 14,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        leading: Image.network(
                                          singleUser.bookimage!,
                                          fit: BoxFit.contain,
                                        ),
                                        /*onTap: (){
                              Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => route[index]));
                            },*/
                                      );
                                    }
                                    return SizedBox();
                                  }

                              );
                            }
                        ),
                      );
                    }
                    return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                  }

              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }


  Widget text_button_preview(context, index){
    return StreamBuilder<List<HighschoolBooksModel>>(
        stream: FirestoreHelper_Highschool.read(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Center(child:
            Text(
              "Some error occurred, please try again later.",
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                fontSize: 20,
              ),),);
          }
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            final userData = snapshot.data;
            final singleUser = userData![index];
            return TextButton(
              child: Text('${singleUser.buttonpreview!}',
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 12
                ),

              ),
              onPressed: (){
                setState(() {
                  Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => webview_preview(context,index)));
                });
              },

            );

          }
          return SizedBox();
        }




    );



  }





  Widget text_button_purchase(context,index){
    return StreamBuilder<List<HighschoolBooksModel>>(
        stream: FirestoreHelper_Highschool.read(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Center(child:
            Text(
              "Some error occurred, please try again later.",
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                fontSize: 20,
              ),),);
          }
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            final userData = snapshot.data;
            final singleUser = userData![index];
            return TextButton(
              child: Text('${singleUser.buttonpurchase!}',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 12,
                ),

              ),
              onPressed: () async{
                await makePayment('${singleUser.price!}', 'GBP');
                
                
                
              },

            );

          }
          return SizedBox();
        }
    );
  }
  

  
  
  
  

  Future<void> makePayment(String amount, String currency) async {
    try {
      paymentIntent = await createPaymentIntent(amount, currency);
      //Payment Sheet
      await Stripe.instance.initPaymentSheet(
          paymentSheetParameters: SetupPaymentSheetParameters(
              paymentIntentClientSecret: paymentIntent!['client_secret'],
              // applePay: const PaymentSheetApplePay(merchantCountryCode: '+92',),
              // googlePay: const PaymentSheetGooglePay(testEnv: true, currencyCode: "US", merchantCountryCode: "+92"),
              style: ThemeMode.dark,
              merchantDisplayName: 'National English')).then((value){
      });


      ///now finally display payment sheeet

      displayPaymentSheet();
    } catch (e, s) {
      print('exception:$e$s');
    }

  }

  displayPaymentSheet() async {

    try {
      await Stripe.instance.presentPaymentSheet(
      ).then((value){
        showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (_) => AlertDialog(
              content: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  Row(
                    children: const [
                      Icon(Icons.check_circle, color: Colors.green,),
                      Text("Payment Successfull"),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ));
        // ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(content: Text("paid successfully")));

        paymentIntent = null;

      }).onError((error, stackTrace){
        print('Error is:--->$error $stackTrace');
      });


    } on StripeException catch (e) {
      print('Error is:---> $e');
      showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (_) => const AlertDialog(
            content: Text("Cancelled "),
          ));
    } catch (e) {
      print('$e');
    }
  }

  //  Future<Map<String, dynamic>>
  createPaymentIntent(String amount, String currency) async {
    try {
      Map<String, dynamic> body = {
        'amount' : amount,
        'currency': currency,
        'payment_method_types[]': 'card'
      };

      var response = await http.post(
        Uri.parse('$YOURURL'),
        headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Bearer $TESTKEY',
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
        body: body,
      );
      // ignore: avoid_print
      print('Payment Intent Body->>> ${response.body.toString()}');
      return jsonDecode(response.body);
    } catch (err) {
      // ignore: avoid_print
      print('err charging user: ${err.toString()}');
    }
  }





  Widget text_button_getinfo(context,index){
    return StreamBuilder<List<HighschoolBooksModel>>(
        stream: FirestoreHelper_Highschool.read(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Center(child:
            Text(
              "Some error occurred, please try again later.",
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                fontSize: 20,
              ),),);
          }
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            final userData = snapshot.data;
            final singleUser = userData![index];
            return TextButton(
              child: Text('${singleUser.buttongetinfo!}',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 12,
                ),

              ),
              onPressed: (){
                setState(() {
                  Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => webview_getinfo(context,index)));
                });
              },

            );

          }
          return SizedBox();
        }




    );
  }



  Widget webview_preview(context,index){
    late WebViewController _webViewController;
    return StreamBuilder<List<HighschoolBooksModel>>(
        stream: FirestoreHelper_Highschool.read(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Center(child:
            Text(
              "Some error occurred, please try again later.",
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                fontSize: 20,
              ),),);
          }
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            final userData = snapshot.data;
            final singleUser = userData![index];
            return Scaffold(
              body: WillPopScope(
                onWillPop: () async{
                  if(await _webViewController.canGoBack()){
                    _webViewController.goBack();
                    return false;
                  }else{
                    return true;
                  }

                },
                child: SafeArea(
                  child: WebView(
                      initialUrl: '${singleUser.previewurl!}',
                      javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                      onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController){
                        _webViewController = webViewController;
                      }
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );

          }
          return SizedBox();
        }

    );
  }


  Widget webview_getinfo(context,index){
    late WebViewController _webViewController;
    return StreamBuilder<List<HighschoolBooksModel>>(
        stream: FirestoreHelper_Highschool.read(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Center(child:
            Text(
              "Some error occurred, please try again later.",
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                fontSize: 20,
              ),),);
          }
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            final userData = snapshot.data;
            final singleUser = userData![index];
            return Scaffold(
              body: WillPopScope(
                onWillPop: () async{
                  if(await _webViewController.canGoBack()){
                    _webViewController.goBack();
                    return false;
                  }else{
                    return true;
                  }

                },
                child: SafeArea(
                  child: WebView(
                      initialUrl: '${singleUser.getinfourl!}',
                      javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                      onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController){
                        _webViewController = webViewController;
                      }
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );

          }
          return SizedBox();
        }

    );
  }

}
```

FIRESTORE HELPER

```
    class FirestoreHelper_Highschool {
    
      static Stream<List<HighschoolBooksModel>> read(){
        final userCollection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('highschool_preview_info').orderBy('order');
        return userCollection.snapshots().map((querySnapshot) => querySnapshot.docs.map((e) => HighschoolBooksModel.fromSnapshot(e)).toList());
      }
    
    
      static Future create(HighschoolBooksModel user) async{
        final userCollection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('highschool_preview_info');
    
        final docRef = userCollection.doc();
    
        final newUser= HighschoolBooksModel(
    
          bookname: user.bookname,
          bookimage: user.bookimage,
          previewurl: user.previewurl,
          price: user.price,
          status: user.status,
          buttonpreview: user.buttonpreview,
          buttonpurchase: user.buttonpurchase,
          buttongetinfo: user.buttongetinfo,
          getinfourl: user.getinfourl,
          booklevel: user.booklevel,
          order: user.order,
          pricesembol: user.pricesembol,
        ).toJson();
        try{
          await docRef.set(newUser);
        }catch(e){
          print("some error occured $e");
        }
    
      }
    }
}
```

FIRESTORE INFO

```
class HighschoolBooksModel{
      final String? bookname;
      final String? bookimage;
      final String? previewurl;
      final int? price;
      final String? pricesembol;
      final int? status;
      final String? buttonpreview;
      final String? buttonpurchase;
      final String? buttongetinfo;
      final String? getinfourl;
      final String? booklevel;
      final int? order;
    
      HighschoolBooksModel({this.bookname,this.bookimage,this.previewurl,this.price,this.pricesembol,this.status,this.buttonpreview,this.buttonpurchase,this.buttongetinfo,this.getinfourl,this.booklevel,this.order});
    
    
      factory HighschoolBooksModel.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snap){
        var snapshot = snap.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
    
        return HighschoolBooksModel(
          bookname: snapshot['bookname'],
          bookimage: snapshot['bookimage'],
          previewurl: snapshot['previewurl'],
          price: snapshot['price'],
          pricesembol: snapshot['pricesembol'],
          status: snapshot['status'],
          buttonpreview: snapshot['buttonpreview'],
          buttonpurchase: snapshot['buttonpurchase'],
          buttongetinfo: snapshot['buttongetinfo'],
          getinfourl: snapshot['getinfourl'],
          booklevel: snapshot['booklevel'],
          order: snapshot['order'],
        );
      }
    
      Map<String,dynamic> toJson() => {
        "bookname": bookname,
        "bookimage": bookimage,
        "previewurl": previewurl,
        "price": price,
        "pricesembol": pricesembol,
        "status": status,
        "buttonpreview": buttonpreview,
        "buttonpurchase": buttonpurchase,
        "buttongetinfo": buttongetinfo,
        "getinfourl": getinfourl,
        "booklevel": booklevel,
        "order": order,
      };
    
    
    
    
    }
```

REGISTER SERVICE FUNCTION

```
Future<User?> createPerson(String name, String email, String password) async {
var user = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
    email: email, password: password);

await _firestore.collection("Person").doc(user.user!.email).set({'FullName': name, 'email': email,});



return user.user;
```

// FIRESTORE CONSOLE SYSTEM

[users system collection without subcollection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RB0A7.png)

[users system collection with subcollection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4LL1.png)

[user system subcollection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bI7vX.png)

Comment: If you could share more details about your solution, it will be appreciated. Welcome!

Comment: No I couldn't fixed my problem, I tried explain to the website give me error about the upload images. I gave my code with image. :/

Comment: OK, Ismail. I saw a comment before mine saying something about it . I think was removed. Sorry about that. Your question was validated. I hope the solution will come as soon as possible, Welcome!

Comment: Thank you, yes you are right. I removed the comment for misunderstanding.